# MuleSoft Importing RAML Specification into Anypoint Studio With RAML Fragments

Tags: raml

We have upgraded to the Crowd Release platform and are now creating API specifications which are using fragments as recommended by MuleSoft. However, we can import the RAML but can not generate the flows. There is no error - no warnings - nothing.

I have included an example.

api.raml

```
#%RAML 1.0
version: v1
title: api
types:
  contactDetails: !include library/types/contactDetails.raml

/contact:
  post:
    body: 
      application/json:
        type: contactDetails
```

types-library.raml

```
#%RAML 1.0 Library

types:
  telephoneNumber: !include ../exchange_modules/fragment-flows-problem-fragment/1.0.0/telephone-number.raml
```

contactDetails.raml

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType
uses:
  contactDetails: ../types-library.raml

properties:
  name:
    type: string
  telephone:
    type: contactDetails.telephoneNumber
```

telephone-numbers.raml (fragment)

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType

description: |
  **includes validation applicable to a contact telephone number**
  ***
  - Minimum length 9
  - Maximum length 15

type: string
displayName: Telephone Number
minLength: 9
maxLength: 15
pattern: ^[\d ]+$
examples:
  telephoneNumber1: "01433000000"
  telephoneNumber2: "01433 000000"
```

I'll just add that the RAML is valid in both Design Center and Exchange.

Just to add, if we remove the uses statement in the contactDetails.raml, then the contactDetails data type is not recognised.

If someone point out a problem here or explain how Anypoint Studio can import specifications which utilise fragments that would be extremely useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late reply but I happened to run into this problem today and my search led me to your question.

The problem for me is a missing `!include` in the contactDetails.raml file.  I had the same problem in Anypoint Studio and my fix would be:

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType
uses:
  contactDetails: !include ../types-library.raml

properties:
  name:
    type: string
  telephone:
    type: contactDetails.telephoneNumber
```

Anypoint Studio unfortunately doesn't give any good information on why there is a RAML error, but just tells you something is wrong.

Comment: You should not use `!include` to load libraries, see here: https://blog.apimatic.io/common-mistakes-developers-make-in-their-raml-files-8da0c427bb07